Regrouping series preserves convergence iff $n_k-k$ is bounded?
Motivation. Given a real sequence $(a_k)_{k=1}^\infty$ with $\lim_{k\to \infty} a_k=0$, denote by $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n a_k$ its $n$-th partial sum. We can easily see that
$$ \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k ~~\text{converges}~~ \Longleftrightarrow ~~ (S_{2n})_{n=1}^\infty ~~\text{converges},$$
since $S_{2n+1} = S_{2n} + a_{2n+1}$. The same thing is true when replacing $(S_{2n})_{n=1}^\infty$ with $(S_{3n})_{n=1}^\infty$, but not necessarily when taking $(S_{n^2})_{n=1}^\infty$ instead, as we can see in (some variation of) the case of the divergent series
$$ 1\color{red}{-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3}
\color{red}{-\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{4}}+\cdots $$
with the regrouping
$$\left( 1- \color{red} {\frac 1 2 -\frac 1 2} \right)+\left(\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3}+ \frac{1}{3} \color{red} {-\frac 1 4 -\frac 1 4-\frac 1 4 -\frac 1 4} \right)+\cdots = 0 +0 +\cdots=0.$$
Question. Let $(n_k)_{k=1}^\infty $ be a strictly ascending sequence of natural numbers. Is it true that the following are equivalent?
(1) $\limsup_{k\to \infty} ({n_{k}-k}) < \infty$.
(2) For every real sequence $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ tending to $0$, the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges iff the sequence $\sum_{n=1}^{n_k} a_n$ converges.
My attempt. The implication $(1)\Longrightarrow (2)$ is true due to the fact that when $({n_{k}-k})_{k=1}^\infty$ is bounded by some $M\in \Bbb N$, for all $\varepsilon >0$, we have $S_{n_k} = S_k + \sum_{n=k}^{n_k} a_n$, and $\left|\sum_{n=k}^{n_k} a_n\right|\leq \sum_{n=k}^{n_k} \left| a_n \right|\leq M\varepsilon$ for large enough $k$. I am not sure how to prove the other implication, if it is true.

Wouldn’t $n_k = 2k$ be a counterexample to the other direction? As you explained at the beginning of your question, (2) is satisfied in this case, but clearly (1) is not. Perhaps you meant $n_k/k$ instead of $n_k-k$?

Rather than $n_k - k$ being bounded, do you want $n_{k+1} - n_k$ to be bounded?

As Misha Lavrov says, the good condition is
$$
\tag{*}\sup_{k\geqslant 1}\left(n_{k+1}-n_k\right)<\infty.
$$
Indeed, suppose that (*) holds and let $(a_n)$ be a sequence that converges to $0$ and such that $\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n_k}a_i\right)$ converges. We show that
$ \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i\right)$ is Cauchy. For fixed $M$, let $k(M)$ be
the index such that $\lvert i-n_{k(M)}\rvert$ is minimal among the quantities
$\lvert i-n_k\rvert$, $k\geq 1$ (if there are two such $k(M)$, choose an arbitrary one among the two). Then for each $M\leqslant N$,
\begin{align}
\left\lvert \sum_{i=M+1}^N a_i\right\rvert&\leq \left(\lvert M-n_{k(M)}\rvert+
\lvert N-n_{k(N)}\rvert\right)\sup_{i\geqslant M}\lvert a_i\rvert+\left\lvert \sum_{i=n_{k(M)}+1}^{n_{k(N)}} a_i\right\rvert\\
&\leqslant \left(\lvert n_{k(M)+1}-n_{k(M)}\rvert+
\lvert n_{k(N)+1}-n_{k(N)}\rvert\right)\sup_{i\geqslant M}\lvert a_i\rvert+\left\lvert \sum_{i=n_{k(M)}+1}^{n_{k(N)}} a_i\right\rvert\\
&\leqslant 2\sup_{k\geqslant 1}\left(n_{k+1}-n_k\right)\sup_{i\geqslant M}\lvert a_i\rvert+\left\lvert \sum_{i=n_{k(M)}+1}^{n_{k(N)}} a_i\right\rvert.
\end{align}
The convergence of $(a_i)$ to $0$ combined with the convergence of
$\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n_k}a_i\right)$ shows that $ \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i\right)$ is Cauchy.
Assume now that $(n_k)$ does not satisfy (*). We will construct a sequence $(a_i)$ converging to $0$, such that $\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n_k}a_i\right)$ converges but the series $\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i$ does not converge. We actually adapt the construct presented in the opening post for $n_k=k^2$. To do so, we can put a equal proportion of terms with their opposite for the $i$ in the discrete interval $\{n_{k}+1,\dots,n_{k+1}\}$ so that the sum on this block vanishes but the sum up
to half of this block has a non-negligible contribution. Here are the details of the construction.
There exists a sequence of integers $(k_u)$ such that for each $u$, $n_{k(u)+1}-n_{k(u)}\geqslant u^2$.
Define $(a_i)$ in the following way. Let $I_k:=\{i, n_{k}+1\leqslant i\leqslant n_{k+1}\}$, $\Delta_k:=n_{k+1}-n_k$, $I_{k,1}=\{i, n_{k}+1\leqslant i\leqslant n_{k}+\lfloor \Delta_k/2\rfloor\}$ and $I_{k,2}=\{i,  \leqslant n_{k}+\lfloor \Delta_k/2\rfloor+1\leqslant i\leqslant n_{k}+2\lfloor \Delta_k/2\rfloor\}$ and $I_{k,3}=\{i,n_{k}+2\lfloor \Delta_k/2\rfloor+1\leqslant i\leqslant n_{k+1}\}$.

If $i\in I_k$ and $k$ does not belong to the set of $\{k_u,u\geqslant 1\}$, then $a_i=0$.
If $i\in I_{k_u,1}$ for some $u\geqslant 1$, define $a_i=\frac{1}{\Delta_{k_u}}$.
If $i\in I_{k_u,2}$ for some $u\geqslant 1$, define $a_i=-\frac{1}{\Delta_{k_u}}$.
If $i\in I_{k_u,3}$ for some $u\geqslant 1$, define $a_i=0$.

Then $(a_i)$ converges to $0$ and the sequence $\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n_k}a_i\right)$ converges. Indeed,
$\sum_{i=1}^{n_k}a_i=\sum_{u:k_u\leqslant k}\sum_{i\in I_{k_u}}a_i=0$
but for each $u$,
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n_{k_u}+\lfloor\Delta_{k_u}/2\rfloor+1}a_i=\frac{\lfloor \Delta_{k_u}/2\rfloor }{\Delta_{k_u}}\to 1/2$$
hence a subsequence of $\left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\right)$ goes to $0$ and an other one to $1/2$.
